# Ruby: Put multiple lines from file

Tags: ruby, string, file

Right, so I have a file in which I want to get two different strings

text.txt:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
abc
ghi
```

How would I go about reading this and printing out two lines? 
I'm currently here:

```
File.open(filename) do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    if line =~ /abc/ 
      puts "Current things: #{line}"
      end
   end
end
```

I was thinking something like this (which obv doesn't work hence the question)

```
File.open(filename) do |f|
  f.each_line do |line,line2|
    if line =~ /abc/ and line2 =~ /ghi/
      puts "Current things: #{line} #{line2}"
      end
   end
end
```

Am I WAY out on this one?

expected output:

```
Current things: abc ghi
```

Comment: What do you mean "two different strings"? Given your input above, what should be the output (and why)?

Comment: Hi Sergio, sorry for being unclear, the output in this case SHOULD be 

"Current things: abc ghi", updating the question as well.

Comment: why not "abc def"?

Comment: Cause I don't want that, I want line 1 and 3 without using line numbers cause they might change 
If you want you can substitute abc with foo, def with bur and ghi with bar, i want foo bar, not foo bur.

Comment: Do you expect the lines to be added to output only if they are in 2 subsequent lines? Or all matches, but unique? It seems like your input would product `abc ghi abc ghi`

Comment: I wanted all matches, which I got in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array to store the matching lines and then print them when finished iterating.

```
File.open(filename) do |f|
  matching_lines = []
  f.each_line do |line|
    if line =~ /abc/ || line =~ /ghi/
      matching_lines << line
    end
  end
  puts "Current things: #{matching_lines.join(' ')}" unless matching_lines.empty?
end
```

Comment: This will produce "Current things: abc ghi abc ghi"

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, a bit shorter solution:

```
lines = File.foreach(filename, chomp: true).each_with_object([]) do |line, arr|
  arr << line if line.match?(/abc|ghi/)
end
puts "Current things: #{lines.join(' ')}" if lines.any?
# => Current things: abc ghi abc ghi
```

If you want unique lines:

```
require 'set'
lines = File.foreach(filename, chomp: true).each_with_object(Set.new) do |line, set|
  set.add(line) if line.match?(/abc|ghi/)
end
puts "Current things: #{lines.to_a.join(' ')}" if lines.any?
# => Current things: abc ghi
```

Comment: I suggest you use [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) rather than `inject` (aka `reduce`), in part to get rid of that pesky `arr` (or `set`) after the colon: `File.foreach(filename, chomp: true).each_with_object([]) { |line, arr| arr << line if line.match?(/abc|ghi/) }`. [String#match?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-match-3F), which, imo, reads better than `=~`, made its debut in MRI v2.4. I wasn't aware of `chomp: true`. Good to know.

Comment: I actually much prefer using `each_with_object` over `inject` when possible, but for some reason I was convinced it was a Rails extension to Enumerable. Big thanks for pointing that out, I guess we both learned today :). I would have used `match?` had I been writing this from scratch, but still, a valid point.
I'll edit the answer to make use of your comments, thanks again.